# Disable Button on Activity, after user interacts with Buttons

Tags: java, android

Im having trouble disabling the Buttons for a particular question in my mQuestionsBank array. I created a mQuestionsAnswered boolean array with the size of the mQuestionsBank array to keep track of the questions that have been answered. Now, when the user interacts with either the "True" or "False" button, mQuestionsAnswered[mCurrentIndex] gets set to true, therefore disabling both of the buttons whether if they are right or wrong. Heres my code

[Method to Enable Buttons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMicu.png)

[Method to Check Answer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsS2u.png)

[True and False Button onClickListeners image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp1xb.png)

Comment: Please, post your code directly on the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from your first picture:

> ```
> private void buttonEnabler(){
>     if (...) {
>         ...
>     } else
>         mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
>         mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
> }
> ```

You're missing brackets on the `else` case. That means that this code "really" looks like this:

```
private void buttonEnabler(){
    if (...) {
        ...
    } else
        mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

In other words, `mFalseButton` will always be enabled, even when you don't want it to be. To fix it, add the brackets surrounding the `else` lines:

```
private void buttonEnabler(){
    if (...) {
        ...
    } else {
        mTrueButton.setEnabled(true);
        mFalseButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method buttonEnable, there's the if else error

Use else with {} brackets always, unless the statements to be executed is just one as illustrated below...

```
if (true)
    say 'hello
else
    be quiet
```

Or

```
if(true) {
    say 'hello'
    say 'how may I help you're
 } else {
    say statement 3
    say statement 4
 }
```